# Use a nested Type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I want to add types to a function which should receive the `items` array of strings:

```
type Inputs = {
  foo: string
  items: string[];
};


const myFunction = (items: string[]) => {
    //
}
```

The code above works but is there a way getting the types from the Inputs type? So something like:

```
const myFunction = (items: Inputs.items) => {
    //
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, but just use bracket notation instead:

```
type Inputs = {
  foo: string
  items: string[];
};


const myFunction = (items: Inputs['items']) => {
  //
}
```